# Matlab, Working with indexes instead of nested For loops (for into for)

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing

So lately I am trying to work with indexes instead of for loops since it looks AND feels way faster on matlab.

So I am trying to change the following;

```
for i =1:size(l,1)
        for j=1:size(l,2)
                     if  l(i,j,1)>200 &&  l(i,j,2)<40 && l(i,j,3)<40
                          l(i,j,1)=144;
                          l(i,j,2)=0;
                          l(i,j,3)=0;

                     end
        end
end
```

into this:

```
p1(:,:,1)= (200 < l(:, :,1) & 40 > l(:, :,2) & 40 > l(:, :,3)) ;
p2(:,:,2)= (200 < l(:, :,1) & 40 > l(:, :,2) & 40 > l(:, :,3));
p3(:,:,3)= (200 < l(:, :,1) & 40 > l(:, :,2) & 40 > l(:, :,3));
pix(p1(:,:,1))=144;
pix(p2(:,:,2))=0;
pix(p3(:,:,3))=0;
```

It is almost working and I can see the pictures , but the colors appear different on both pics. I mean that imshow(pix) doesn't look exactly the same as imshow(l). I really cant spot the problem.

Comment: this is probably a rescaling of the colormap that is happening because you changed the min to max intensity values if your image...

Comment: @natan I dont understand what you mean. If from the 1st part delete the lines5 and 6 , and from the second part of the code delete the lines 2,3,5 and 6. The images look exactly the same. Any insight on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick fix, using vectors to reference matrix elements refers to more elements than you intend. It still has one for loop though, but it should be quicker than your original method.

```
[ti,tj]=find(pix(:,:,1)>200 &  pix(:,:,2)<40 & pix(:,:,3)<40);
for k=1:length(ti)
    pix(ti(k),tj(k),:)=[144 0 0];
end
```

Comment: Oops, be careful: this solution does not return the desired outcome.

Comment: Re-checked, my mistake (where pix = l).

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
% This is how the data look like
q = randi(256, [1000, 1000, 3]);

% This is the desired outcome:
tic
qq = q;
for i = 1:size(q, 1)
        for j = 1:size(q, 2)
                     if  ((q(i, j, 1) > 200) && (q(i, j, 2) < 40) && (q(i, j, 3) < 40))
                          qq(i, j, 1) = 144;
                          qq(i, j, 2) = 0;
                          qq(i, j, 3) = 0;
                     end
        end
end
toc

% This is a faster solution    
tic
p1(:, :, 1) = (q(:, :, 1) > 200) & (q(:, :, 2) < 40) & (q(:, :, 3) < 40);
p2(:, :, 2) = p1(:, :, 1);
p3(:, :, 3) = p1(:, :, 1);
pix = q;
pix(p1(:)) = 144;
pix(p2(:)) = 0;
pix(p3(:)) = 0;
toc

% Check that the solution returns the desired outcome:    
all(pix(:) == qq(:))
sum(pix(:) ~= qq(:))
```